# To Remove Comma at the end of each line in a very huge File (5GB) in Unix

Tags: bash, unix, sed, sh, ksh

Input

```
"India","Australia",1991-07-03,99,
1991-07-03,99,"India","Australia",
```

Above is just a sample lines in the file. The length of 1 line is 1800 (approx). The size of the file is 5 GB. Each Line ends with <,CRLF> (Carraige Feed Line Feed) Character. I need to remove the , from it.

Output

```
"India","Australia",1991-07-03,99
1991-07-03,99,"India","Australia"
```

Command I Used

```
cat InputFile | sed 's~,\r~\r~g' > OutputFile.
```

Problem

The Command is working fine , but it's taking 15 minutes to get the changes done.

Question

Is there any other fast/better way to do this quickly?

Comment: Note that there is no point use `cat` here, use `sed 's~,\r~\r~g' InputFile > OutputFile`

Comment: Do you actually have to remove the trailing `,` or can you e.g. replace it by a space?

Comment: Try: `sed 's/,\r$//' file > output`

Comment: I've to actually have to remove the trailing ,

Comment: Then there is no way around rewriting 5 GB of data.

Comment: As an aside, keeping the DOS line endings seems misdirected.

Comment: What about this one : `awk '1' RS=',\r' ORS='\r' inputfile` ? You can test it without redirecting the output to another file to see how fast does it perform. Then you can try `awk '1' RS=',\r' ORS='\r' inputfile >outputfile`. I think you need gawk to run this command.

Comment: cut -d, -f1-3 InputFile > OutputFile

Comment: I second @WiktorStribiżew useless `cat` and it is likely the main bottleneck of the file processing with `sed` having the file sent byte by byte through a pipe instead of buffering whole lines at a time.

Comment: any chance you have a slow disk/subsystem that's having problems reading/writing the 5GB at the same time?  if you have a second filesystem mounted from a different disk/subsystem you may want to see if you can write the output to the 2nd filesystem (ie, read from one disk/subsystem and write to another disk/subsystem)

Comment: Agree with @markp that 15 mins seems way too long regardless of how inefficient your `sed` command is (well, within reason). On even my old sucky system, I can write 1 GB in a minute.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou This might be faster than sed but it should be `awk '1' RS=',\r\n' ORS='\r\n' inputfile > outputfile`

Comment: If you run the multiple solutions offered on this thread, please do us all a favor and precede each run with the cmd `time`, i.e. `time sed 's/,$//' file > outFile` and post the results. Will upvote your Q and A for that! Good luck.

Comment: I Checked the comments provided here , and the problem lies with the NAS Drive in which the operation happens. A simple mv file1 file2 within the NAS mount for a 5GB file takes 15 minutes.  Need to check with Admin Team why such a huge delay

Answer (score 2):

If you want significant speed-up, I'm afraid you're going to need to go to a compiled-code solution. Perl, Java, c. Here is c code that I have tested and works for your case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int c, d;
    c = getchar();
    if (c == EOF) return 0; // edge case, empty file
    for (d = getchar(); d != EOF; c = d, d = getchar())
            if (c != ',' || d != '\r') putchar(c);
    putchar(c); // last char in file
}
```

I guess I should add how to bare-bones run that code. Of course you'll need a c compiler, cc. Assuming so, put the above code into a file comma.c, then:

```
$ cc comma.c
$ ./a <InputFile >OutputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make this faster, you can try using split. https://kb.iu.edu/d/afar

Split the file into numerous smaller files, then do a threaded loop against the resulting smaller files, and output the sed of each smaller file into a new results file.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to remove comma at the end of every line is with sed command:

```
sed -i 's/,$//' input-file
```

If you don't want to modify the original file you can create a new output file like this:

```
sed 's/,$//' input-file > output-file
```